# Is it possible to combine the ANY and BETWEEN operator

Tags: postgresql

I need to check if any value in a Postgres array is between a given range. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ANY(my_array) BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

I realize that I can't actually do this, since the ANY operator must always be on the right side of the expression.  Does anyone know of a convenient work around for doing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-range.html), specifically the range membership operator `@>`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE '[50,60]'::int4range @> ANY(my_array);
```

If you need to pull the range bounds from a column or parameter, the range constructor function might suit you better:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE int4range(a,b,'[]') @> ANY(my_array);
```

Comment: You can use `int4range(50,60, '[]')` to specify that the range should include both bounds.

Comment: @Marth: Cool, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you need range

```
select array_agg(q.arr) arr
from (
    select unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) arr
) q
where q.arr between 3 and 5
```